# How to create high quality map with QGIS and Stamen tiles

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapping, inkscape

I'm wanting to create a simple but high quality map in QGIS with two minimal vector layers and Stamen's landscape tiles as a basemap. When viewing my map in the QGIS print composer everything looks great, but a .png export of the map from the print composer looks a lot different. I know that this issue is somewhat common and I'm not dead set on using the QGIS print composer.

I've tried saving the map as a .png straight from QGIS (not in the print composer), and this looks pretty good but obviously does included a needed legend, scale bar, etc. I've tried importing this .png into Inkscape to manually include map elements, but the resolution always looks reduced in Inkscape. Can I use QGIS, Stamen tiles, and Inkscape to create a high quality map, or would other tools better fit this task?

Comment: You cannot use low-res pre-rendered tiles to create quality high-res maps. You need to change your approach!

Comment: @underdark Ok good to know. Any suggestions for alternative tile sources then? Or a different approach in general?

Comment: @underdark links would be fine btw

Comment: Did you consider to download OSM ?

Comment: @Azimo Yes, but from my understanding I would have to download the OSM data as images, and these won't be georeferenced, correct? I may have a misunderstanding here and would be open to trying though.

Comment: I guess it depends on what elements from OSM you need. If you need most (or all) of the element displayed on usual tiles and if you need to make maps on various places with various zoom levels etc. it seems logical to use tiles and you can render your own (there is some tutorials on https://switch2osm.org/ for example and you can also take a look at the official OSM wiki). If you have less constraints (almost always same zoom, only want to display roads for example, etc.) you can also download OSM data as shapefiles, and style them according to your needs in QGIS for example.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the helpful information so far. I should have been more specific - I'd particularly like to use Stamen's landscape tiles for this project. I've edited my question to make it more specific.

Comment: @Matt - check the instructions from Underdark about using OSM data (same as Stamen uses) with some style files she has made -these have completely changed print cartography for us - we're doing both 36x24" plots and static images with the OSM lines styled with the 'Google' / colour version, and a black and white style I modified (I should share these soon), but this and the 'Toner Lite' style might get you what you need ... you'll get VERY crisp vector data and labels and you can change the colour values to match your printer if you want...

Comment: Tutorial: http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/ Styles: https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite

Comment: @underdark these are the best... I need to send you the modifications I've made and the greyscale version...

Comment: @mapBaker - Thanks for your comments. This got me where I needed to go. My maps look great now and very crisp like you said. I see now that I had a misunderstanding in how Stamen/OSM pre-rendered tiles work compared to loading the data in QGIS as vector data. If my question ever gets reopened, feel free to post your info as an answer, and I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @Matt that's great to hear! Would love to see what you came up with... re. the 'closed' question, it's par for the course... thanks, and good luck!!!

Comment: @mapBaker This is a start: http://imgh.us/greenwood-2.png . I'd also be interested in contributing to these sorts of things if you know where needs exist!

Comment: @Matt that looks great!!! yeah if more of us start using those styles, and customizing them as we have, we should build a new repository for them and keep them up to date...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the instructions from Underdark about using OSM data (same as Stamen uses) with some style files she has made (see below for links)

[image]

These have completely changed print cartography for us - we're doing both 36x24" plots and static images with the OSM lines styled with the 'Google' / colour version, and a black and white style I modified (I should share these soon), but this and the 'Toner Lite' style might get you what you need ... you'll get VERY crisp vector data and labels and you can change the colour values to match your printer if you want.

**Tutorial is here**:
http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/

**Styles are here**:
https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite

For another greyscale version, and our updated colour version, check our Github repo here: https://github.com/dpsspatial/Styles/tree/master/QGIS_OSM

[image]

Another tip is once you've got the styles in as a group layer in your map, QGIS gives the ability to toggle the layers in the group on/off as you see fit - so you don't always have to render the 'minor roads' for example...

[image]