# Error during load osm pbf file from QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pbf

I was trying to print out Stamen map (Quickmap plugin) in very high quality. However, I was unable to do so, printed out results looks like chequer board or empty.

So, I was following the information from
[How to create high quality map with QGIS and Stamen tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186808/how-to-create-high-quality-map-with-qgis-and-stamen-tiles) and 
https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/

And I downloaded osm.pbf for asia from http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html here.

Problem is, OSGeo4W shell makes warning messages while I tried to transform pbf to db file:

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES D:\QGIS_Korea\test2.db D:\QGIS_Korea\asia-latest.osm.pbf
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry.  Either a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points, or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection.
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry.  Either a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points, or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection.
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry.  Either a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points, or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection.
100 - done.
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry.  Either a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points, or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection.
Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry.  Either a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points, or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection.
```

Anyway it finished the conversion. But when I try to add them to my project via add layer -> Spatialite layer -> new -> choose file -> connect, it prints out following error message.

```
Spatial metadata check failed 
Failure getting table metadata... is ****.db file really a SpatiaLite database? 
table info on geometry_columns failed 
database is locked
```

How can I escape from this situation?

Comment: You are processing the entire Asian continent. Did you try to process only one country (i.e., [South Korea subregion](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/south-korea.html))?  Also, you can try with the `-explodecollections` option, I would think that the problem can be a [multipolygon relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation%3amultipolygon): `ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -explodecollections D:\QGIS_Korea\test2.db D:\QGIS_Korea\asia-latest.osm.pbf`

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thank you so much, I didn't know about country data. I will try explode collection option